# Can I turn Azura's star from white to black?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've already turned Azura's star white and now when I see of it over the Internet it's just been wasted can I turn it black now?

Answer (score 4):

No, once you've finished this quest there's no in-game method of converting the star from one form to another.  I wouldn't lose sleep (or significant game progress) as a result of your choice - soul gems are reasonably common, even black ones, so Azura's Star is not particularly essential in either form.

On the PC, you could use the console to give yourself a [Black Star](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Black_Star_%28item%29):

```
player.additem 00063b29 1
```

As always, I suggest backing up your save prior to using the console, as mistakes made with it can sometimes cause damage to your game.